# Take the array value in order and assign a link to the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello i have some blocks in HTML

```
<div class="feed_name"><img height="50">      
<div class="feed_name"><img height="50">
<div class="feed_name"><img height="50">
<div class="feed_name"><img height="50">
```

and some code js

```
    var images = ["50.jpg","51.jpg","52.jpg","53.jpg","54.jpg","55.jpg","56.jpg","57.jpg","58.jpg","59.jpg","60.jpg","61.jpg","62.jpg","63.jpg","64.jpg","65.jpg","66.jpg","67.jpg","68.jpg","69.jpg","70.jpg","71.jpg","72.jpg","73.jpg","74.jpg","75.jpg","76.jpg","77.jpg","78.jpg","79.jpg","80.jpg","81.jpg","82.jpg","83.jpg","84.jpg","85.jpg","86.jpg","87.jpg","88.jpg","89.jpg","90.jpg"];
 var target = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
 var returnImages = [];
 var currentImages;
    function getUnique(count) {
        // Make a copy of the array
        var tmp = images.slice(images);
        var ret = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * tmp.length);
            var removed = tmp.splice(index, 1);
            // Since we are only removing one element
            ret.push('img/users/' + removed[0]);
                $(".feed_name img").each(
                    $(".feed_name img").attr("src", ret[i])
                );

        }
        return ret;

    }

    returnImages.push(getUnique(6));
    console.log(returnImages);
```

I want to make all image different form array returnImage but dont know how, pls help

Comment: just to understand: if you'd pick randomly 80.jpg 54.jpg and 61.jpg do you want to show them in that order or should they be shown in order (54,61,80) ?

Comment: no matter any option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My VanillaJS attempt

```js
/* a simple Array shuffler helper */
var shuffle = function(array) {
  var a =  array.slice(0);
  a.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
  return a;
}

/* retrieve all the nodes of the images */
var imagesNode = document.querySelectorAll('.feed_name img');

/* fill an array of integers [50,...,90] */
var imagesUrl = Array(41).fill(0).map((i, j) => j + 50);

/* shuffle the array, limit the length of the array to the length 
 * of the nodes and - if you need it - sort() it again 
 */
var imagesPicked = shuffle(imagesUrl).slice(0, imagesNode.length).sort();

/* set images url */
[...imagesNode].map((node) => {
   var num = imagesPicked.shift();
   node.src = num + '.jpg';
   node.title = "this is the image number " + num;
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="feed_name"><img /></div>      
  <div class="feed_name"><img /></div>
  <div class="feed_name"><img /></div>
  <div class="feed_name"><img /></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a JS way there are way to attach the img tag to the div container.

```
var items = [imgaddr1, imgaddr2, imgaddr3];
var target = document.querySelector("img-container");

items.forEach(function(item) {
   var img = document.createElement("img");
   img.src = item;
   target.appendChild(img);
});
```

HTML code

```
<div id="img-container">
```

JQuery code

```
$(items).each(function(key, value) {
 $('div#img-container').append("<div><img src='" + value + "' /> 
 </div>");
});
```

Comment: Thank you also appreciate your help.